# for loop with only terminating expression vs while loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Whilst browsing the Apache ActiveMQ source code, i came across a funny looking for loop..

```
 for (;beforeEndIndex < size;) {
     synchronizations.get(beforeEndIndex++).beforeEnd();
 }
```

Whats the benifit of this over using a standard while loop?

E.G.

```
while(beforeEndIndex < size){
    beforeEndIndex++;
}
```

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis So its just a wierd way of writing the same logic?

Comment: yes it does the same thing. I find it weird if any of the 3 parts of a `for` are missing buy it can be useful to limit the scope of a variable. Not in this case though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both do exactly the same thing.

The major difference between a `for` loop and a `while` loop is that the `for` loop limits the scope of the iteration counter to within the `for` block where as a `while` loop requires you to declare the iteration counter at least one block higher. In this case, as the `for` loop declares no iteration counter variable, there is no difference.